# I want to prevent printing twice

Tags: python, if-statement, printing

Yesterday, I was helped by a grateful person to solve the problem, but it was blocked again. If I print it out like the picture below, the part `error! ~` is output twice. If I change the order of what is written after `if` and what `else` is written, it is printed twice. How can I solve this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Paste your code, not image of it please. Do not nest every `if`

Comment: Dont have a function definition inside a for loop.

Comment: [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are running the function twice, once in the if statement, and once in the print. Store it in a variable like so:

```py
# ...

for i in range(0, 5):

    # ...
    # ...

    bibeon = input("Enter password: ")
    chkResult = passwordChk(bibeon)
    if chkResult == 'Valid Password':
        print(chkResult)
        break
    else:
        print(chkResult)
```